# forEach on a map function js assertion test not running

Tags: javascript, error-handling, assertion

I am currently working on an assertion test for a map/ cubeAll function. I have revised my logic and my syntax multiple times already and I haven't been able to discover why the compiler is throwing a "Type Error array.forEach is not a function" error. I have read the MDN page about TypeError errors and I know that my " forEach" tried to call a value from a function and that Array.prototype.forEach need a callback function to work properly. According to my logic, in my code (coming below), I do have a callback function and I am tried to call a value from passing each element of my array into this call back. What is wrong?

```
function map(array, callbackFunction) {
  var newArray = [];
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    newArray.push(callbackFunction(element));
  });
  return newArray;
}

function cubeAll(numbers) {
  return map(numbers, function(n) {
    return n * n * n;
  });
}

function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
  let arraysHaveEqualLength = actual.length === expected.length;
  let arraysHaveSameElements = actual.every(function(ele,idx){
    return ele === expected[idx];
  });
  if(arraysHaveEqualLength && arraysHaveSameElements){
    console.log(`${testName} has passed.`);
  }else {
    console.log(`${testName} has FAILED. Expected ${expected} and got ${actual} instead.`);
  }
}
```

Cases I am trying to test :

```
assertArraysEqual(map([3,2,1],cubeAll),[27,8,1], 'it should return a new array with all the elements cubed');
assertArraysEqual(map([3,2,1],cubeAll),[27,7,1], 'it should return a new array with all the elements cubed');
```

The error in the console :

```
 array.forEach(element => newArray.push(callbackFunction(element)));
        ^

TypeError: array.forEach is not a function
```

Thanks!

Comment: seems weird you use array forEach and evety, but you do not use array.map() and why are you calling map() from inside of cubeAll ?

Comment: im confused why you are calling `map` from `cubeAll` and your assert...

Comment: you're calling `cubeAll` on each number in the array passed to `map`. Since `cubeAll` calls `map` on the param provided, you're calling `map` on an individual number value, which doesn't have a `forEach` method.

Comment: My initial thought was to cube all the numbers first inside the cubeAll function and then assign the resulting array to the final array in map. It didn't work out that well so I ended up just simplifying my cubeAll function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `cubeAll` receives a number rather than an array.

```
function cubeAll(n) {
    return n * n * n;
}
```

You can use the built-in object `Math` and function `.pow(...)`:

```
return Math.pow(n, 3);
```

For environment which supports ES2016 (evergreen browsers, node 7+)

```
function cubeAll(n) {
    return n ** 3;
}
```

```js
function map(array, callbackFunction) {
  var newArray = [];
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    newArray.push(callbackFunction(element));
  });
  return newArray;
}

function cubeAll(n) {
  return n ** 3;
}

function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
  let arraysHaveEqualLength = actual.length === expected.length;
  let arraysHaveSameElements = actual.every(function(ele,idx){
    return ele === expected[idx];
  });
  if(arraysHaveEqualLength && arraysHaveSameElements){
    console.log(`${testName} has passed.`);
  }else {
    console.log(`${testName} has FAILED. Expected ${expected} and got ${actual} instead.`);
  }
}


assertArraysEqual(map([3,2,1],cubeAll),[27,8,1], 'it should return a new array with all the elements cubed');
assertArraysEqual(map([3,2,1],cubeAll),[27,7,1], 'it should return a new array with all the elements cubed');
```

Comment: I successfully changed my cubeAll function to be just the result of multiplying the given argument three times. I hadn't realized that I was passing a single argument into my cubeAll function thus I kept on passing a single element to it. Thanks!

Comment: Small tip, if you're in an environment which supports ES2016 (evergreen browsers, node 7+) the exponentiation operator is a thing: http://2ality.com/2016/02/exponentiation-operator.html